# is it possible to password protect ms-access 2007 file without encryption

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a large 1.3 GB accdb file to which I added security by password protecting it. Accdb file enforces encryption along with password protection so now i am not able to Compress it with winzip.

Is it possible to password protect that file without encryption.
Any help is greatly appriciated as both are must for the work i am doing. 
Thanks,
Ashwin

Comment: You could put the password protection in your zip file

Comment: If you do use WinZip password-protection, make sure you use a relatively new version. The old .zip encryption scheme was extremely weak.

Comment: Database passwords are not security -- they are security THEATER and are simply not worth using. With a 1.3GB compacted data file, you should really be looking to upsize to a database engine that accomodates more than 2GBs of data before you run into real trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You *need* to be able to compress it with WinZip? And you want to password-protect but not encrypt? A dirty solution for a dirty problem: you *could* create a virtual encrypted drive (or similar scheme) that is password protected and put the database file there... When WinZip reads it it'll seem unencrypted, but you need the password to access the file itself.

If the data is actually unencrypted and users have access to it, then any password protection scheme would simply be there as a visual placebo for the ignorant (or an annoyance for the knowing).

The common solution would be not to let users access the file itself, but force them to go through a database server that has authentication...